# Symfony 3 entity constant to text in twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I would like to be albe to translate an entity defined constant to its related text-value.
*I removed most of the code that doesn't relate to the problem for better overview.*

**Todo Entity**

```
/**
 * Todo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="todo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TodoBundle\Repository\TodoRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Todo
{
    const PRIORITY_HIGH = 2;
    const PRIORITY_NORMAL = 1;
    const PRIORITY_LOW = 0;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"new", "edit"})
     * @Assert\Choice(callback="getPriorities")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="priority", type="integer")
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * Set priority
     *
     * @param integer $priority
     *
     * @return Todo
     */
    public function setPriority($priority)
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get priority
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPriority()
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    /**
     * Get all priorities
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public static function getPriorities()
    {
        return array(
            'High'      => self::PRIORITY_HIGH,
            'Normal'    => self::PRIORITY_NORMAL,
            'Low'       => self::PRIORITY_LOW
        );
    }
}
```

**Twig Overview**

```
{% for todo in todos %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ todo.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ todo.content }}</td>
        <td>{{ todo.priority }}</td> *Change this to output High, Normal or Low according to its set priority*
        <td>{{ todo.duedate|date('d/m/Y') }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a href="{{ path('todo.show', {'id': todo.id }) }}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                <a href="{{ path('todo.edit', {'id': todo.id }) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                <a href="{{ path('todo.delete', {'id': todo.id }) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When creating a form using the FormBuilder I am able to call this piece of code

```
->add('priority', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'   => Todo::getPriorities()
))
```

to create the dorpdown field with the text and values filled in like this

```
<select id="new_priority" name="new[priority]" class="form-control">
    <option value="2">High</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Normal</option>
    <option value="0">Low</option>
</select>
```

I hope this is possible to do or achieve in another way, it would be useful to implement translations in a later stadium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it using another method that returns an associative array in a reverse way, that is, in example:

```
public static function getPrioritiesForSelect()
{
    return array(
        self::PRIORITY_HIGH      => 'High',
        self::PRIORITY_NORMAL    => 'Normal',
        self::PRIORITY_LOW       => 'Low'
    );
}
```

Then, you will be able to translate strings like "High", "Normal", etc.

If you don't like that solution, if you're using a translation structure based on a translation id string, then, you could create another method again that returns a concatenated string composed by a prefix and your constant's value, then, translate it. Something like this:

```
public static function getPrioritiesForSelect()
{
    return array(
        'High'      => 'string.priority.' . self::PRIORITY_HIGH,
        'Normal'    => 'string.priority.' . self::PRIORITY_NORMAL,
        'Low'       => 'string.priority.' . self::PRIORITY_LOW
    );
}
```

In your translation file you will have something like this:

```
string:
    priority:
        2: 'High'
        1: 'Normal'
        0: 'Low'
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing at way differen and used twigextensions to convert back to the text representation. But yours works too and is a simpler imprementation!